# Import external JS links in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a Responsive Testimonial HTML File. It works on codepen (link is [Here](https://codepen.io/nahidul/pen/yPzwMK) ) and is working nicely. When I transferred it on sublimetext, it doesn't seem to work. I believe it is due to the placement of my *< script >* codes. As we all know, the format of codepen is different from that of an actual code. Can someone tell me where I went wrong? I am confused on how to import or declare external JS links and the positioning. Thanks in advance

Here is what I made **(UPDATE, I removed the main.js and saved it separately, and called it out. I believe the format is vendor first then the main.js)**

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Responsive Testimonials</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" /> 
  <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="css/boostrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="css/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.thenahid.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

  <section>
  <div class="customer-feedback">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
          <div>
            <h2 class="section-title">What Clients Say</h2>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /End col -->
      </div><!-- /End row -->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
          <div class="feedback-slider">

            <!-- slider item -->
            <div class="feedback-slider-item">
              <img src="//c2.staticflickr.com/8/7310/buddyicons/24846422@N06_r.jpg" class="center-block img-circle" alt="Customer Feedback">
              <h3 class="customer-name">Lisa Redfern</h3>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable its layout.</p>
              <span class="light-bg customer-rating" data-rating="5">
                5
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <!-- /slider item -->

            <!-- slider item -->
            <div class="feedback-slider-item">
              <img src="//c2.staticflickr.com/2/1558/buddyicons/37689138@N07_r.jpg" class="center-block img-circle" alt="Customer Feedback">
              <h3 class="customer-name">Cassi</h3>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable its layout.</p>
              <span class="light-bg customer-rating" data-rating="4">
                4
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <!-- /slider item -->

            <!-- slider item -->
            <div class="feedback-slider-item">
              <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/451270/profile/profile-80.jpg" class="center-block img-circle" alt="Customer Feedback">
              <h3 class="customer-name">Md Nahidul</h3>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable its layout.</p>
              <span class="light-bg customer-rating" data-rating="5">
                5
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <!-- /slider item -->

          </div><!-- /End feedback-slider -->

          <!-- side thumbnail -->
          <div class="feedback-slider-thumb hidden-xs">
            <div class="thumb-prev">
              <span>
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/451270/profile/profile-80.jpg" alt="Customer Feedback">
              </span>
              <span class="light-bg customer-rating">
                5
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              </span>
            </div>

            <div class="thumb-next">
              <span>
                <img src="//c2.staticflickr.com/2/1558/buddyicons/37689138@N07_r.jpg" alt="Customer Feedback">
              </span>
              <span class="light-bg customer-rating">
                4
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /side thumbnail -->

        </div><!-- /End col -->
      </div><!-- /End row -->
    </div><!-- /End container -->
  </div><!-- /End customer-feedback -->
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

***JAVASCRIPT main.js***

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var feedbackSlider = jQuery('.feedback-slider');
  feedbackSlider.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    nav: true,
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
    loop: true,
    mouseDrag: true,
    touchDrag: true,
    navText: ["<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-left'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-right'></i>"],
    responsive:{

      // breakpoint from 767 up
      767:{
        nav: true,
        dots: false
      }
    }
  });

  feedbackSlider.on("translate.owl.carousel", function(){
    $(".feedback-slider-item h3").removeClass("animated fadeIn").css("opacity", "0");
    $(".feedback-slider-item img, .feedback-slider-thumb img, .customer-rating").removeClass("animated zoomIn").css("opacity", "0");
  });

  feedbackSlider.on("translated.owl.carousel", function(){
    $(".feedback-slider-item h3").addClass("animated fadeIn").css("opacity", "1");
    $(".feedback-slider-item img, .feedback-slider-thumb img, .customer-rating").addClass("animated zoomIn").css("opacity", "1");
  });
  feedbackSlider.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(property) {
    var current = property.item.index;
    var prevThumb = $(property.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).prev().find("img").attr('src');
    var nextThumb = $(property.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).next().find("img").attr('src');
    var prevRating = $(property.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).prev().find('span').attr('data-rating');
    var nextRating = $(property.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).next().find('span').attr('data-rating');
    $('.thumb-prev').find('img').attr('src', prevThumb);
    $('.thumb-next').find('img').attr('src', nextThumb);
    $('.thumb-prev').find('span').next().html(prevRating + '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>');
    $('.thumb-next').find('span').next().html(nextRating + '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>');
  });
  $('.thumb-next').on('click', function() {
    feedbackSlider.trigger('next.owl.carousel', [300]);
    return false;
  });
  $('.thumb-prev').on('click', function() {
    feedbackSlider.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [300]);
    return false;
  });

}); //end ready
```

Below is the OUTPUT that is showing our what I have right now. I believe it has something to do on how I declare the css and js external codes [My Current Output](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQMmxM#anon-login)

Comment: Make sure that CSS are loaded properly and remove `);` code at end of your jquery code.

Comment: I tried doing that. I do think the css is loading. Still the only difference now is that, all the image and content are stretched and stocked on top of each other

Answer (score 0):

**Edit the scr to src in this**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="js/main.js"></script>
```